# Como adicionar essas referências no VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Não estou encontrando essas referências com a exclamação em Add Reference, alguém sabe como adicionar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Verifica se você está usando a mesma Framework da versão em que você adicionou as referências, exemplo: Se a referência `System.IO` for para o Framework 4.5 e você estiver num Framework 4, irá resultar erro.

Normalmente, essas *Assembly* é automáticamente adicionada no Visual Studio 2008 para cima, mas se quiser procurar manualmente, tente nessas pasta:

```
Para .NET Framework 4.0 pra cima:
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\(Versão do seu Framework)\

Para .NET Framework 3.0 ou 3.5:
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\[v3.5 ou v3.0]\
```

---

Se não encontrar elas, **verifica onde você baixou elas, e onde elas se encontram, verifica se elas existem no local ou se são arquivos não-corrompidos, se for, baixe novamente.**